# In Unity, how can I get a 2d Polygon collider that is the area of a big collider subtract some smaller collider inside the big one?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, physics-engine

Like the image attached, I want to get a polygon collider of the area of the biggest collider subtract the areas of these two smaller colliders inside the big one?

I just want to have a collider that covers only the gray area in the image below.

At runtime please, it's ok to get a composite / polygon or what other types of collider.

Thanks very much.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure but you could use separate box colliders to get the same affect. Just need multiple references in the script.

Comment: Remember to green check any answers that help. Improves other's reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way would indeed be to have 3 separate Colliders, and when collision happens with the big one, you also check that it does NOT happen with the two smaller colliders.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Clipper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/) library for polygon operations (also worth checking the [eppz! Geometry](https://github.com/Geri-Borbas/Unity.Library.eppz.Geometry) library, which itself uses Clipper).

You can then use the resulting polygon "paths" (as it's called in the Clipper library) to create several [EdgeCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EdgeCollider2D.html)s (you can [set its points][4] to create the shape of each polygon.

There is a problem with this approach though, which is that in the end you will not have a "solid" collider with an inside and an outside, and instead you will just have lines to collide with. Hopefully this will not be an issue for most of the cases.